# Moment.js doesn't like my time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, cfc

I am returning a SQL date from JSON and it looks like this: **ts '2017-03-11 00:00:00'**

When I try to apply the `moment.js` formatting, I am receiving this error:

> *Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
>   reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are
>   discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.*

How can I fix this?

Here is my Code:

```
<script>
  function PopulateReviewTimeStamps() {
    // Populate timestamp data div
    console.log("Review timestamp CFC called");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'cfcs/reviewdata.cfc?method=getTimeStampData&returnformat=json',
      data: {
        ticket_id: $("##ticket_id").attr("Value")
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("success function called");
        var value = response;
        var datetime = moment(value);
        var date = datetime.format('MMMM Do, YYYY');
        var time = datetime.format('h:mma');


        // append new option to list
        console.log("about to change div" + value);
        $('##sentDate').html(date + " at " + time);


        // PopulateOdometers();
      },
      error: function(msg) {
        console.log("Something went wrong with populating stats function");
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

UPDATE:
I changed from AJAX request to return the type "date". I no longer recieve invalid date, but my date shows as: November 5th, 2000 at 12:00am.

Console Log is as follows:
Orignal date value: March, 11 2017 00:00:00 -0500 <----- Before moments.js is run

about to change div to: November 5th, 200012:00am <----- This is after moments.js is run

Comment: [Pass `moment()` the pattern for your date format.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Does the value actually contain `ts` and those single quotes?

Comment: It stored is my DB as: 2017-03-10 00:00:00

But the console.log shows: about to change div{ts '2017-03-11 00:00:00'}

Comment: Is there a way to strip the ts and the quotes first?

Answer (score 2):

This:-

```
var datetime = moment(value);
```

Need to be:-

```
var datetime = moment(value,'MM-DD-YYYY h:m'); // pass desired date-time format
```

Reference:- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/  (by Pointy)